# Why does system monitor show slightly MORE memory than I have?

Tags: 18.04, ram, system

The screenshot says it all. The RAM sticks report 16GB each, but System monitor shows 33.5GBs. This is an ASUS ROG Strix laptop from 3 years ago, but I only noticed now:
[image]

On the other hand, "About" shows a different story:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, a "gigabyte" is measured as a multiple of 1024. But that isn't very metric thus a "gigabyte" is now measured by a multiple of 1000.

Your device has 32 × 1024 ³ = 34359738368 bytes of RAM. By the newer definition that's 34.4 GB. Some RAM is reserved for the firmware hence your number of 33.5 GB.

Comment: Note the different shortcuts "GiB" and "GB" on the two screenshots. When the definition of "GB" has been changed to decimal, the old-style "binary" GB has been renamed to "GiB" (gibibyte).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the system monitor is counting the RAM in "GB", but the about page is counting the RAM as "GiB". There is nothing to worry about since it's just that the about page and the system monitor page counts the RAM differently.